# Finite simple group has order a multiple of 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, finite-groups, simple-groups, groups-of-lie-type

Checking the list of finite simple groups, it seemed to me that all groups have order a multiple of $3$. This clear for alternating groups and checked case by case for sporadic groups. For groups of Lie type it looked like the orders are always multiples of $q(q^2 - 1)$ for a prime power $q$, and this quantity is always a multiple of $3$.

Upon closer inspection there is an outlier, namely the Suzuki groups. Are these the only exception? Is there a reason why this is the case, or is it just a corollary of the classification?

I have seen that there are many constructions of the Suzuki groups. Could you recommend a reference to read about them?

Comment: Since the order of the finite simple non-abelian groups is always divisible by $4$ and since $3$ or $5$ must be a prime factor as well (see my answer below) , we can say that the order of every finite simple non-abelian group is divisible by $12$ or by $20$

Comment: I think that only the classification of the finite simple groups gives this result.

Comment: Another very intersting consequence of the classification : For every positive integer $n$, there are at most two simple groups with order $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all : We must assume that the group is non-abelian, otherwise the cyclic groups with prime order , except $\mathbb Z_3$ , would already be counterexamples.

The Suzuki groups have orders not divisible by $3$, $5$ is however always a prime factor of the order of those groups. All the other finite simple non-abelian groups have order divisible by $3$.